# Issue with applying fadeIn

Tags: jquery, flash

I have flash embeded on my page but then i am using jquery to add a fadeIn effect to the page but it does not work for the embedded flash.

In other words, the flash content loads up first before the rest. So i thought maybe i could use jquery to wrap a div round the flash and then fade the div out, but the problem i encounter here is that the flash is on top of the div.

Is there something obvious i am missing or a neater way to get around this?

```
$('#flash').wrap("<div id='me'></div>");
$('#me').css({'background':'#ff0000', 'position' : 'absolute'});
$('#me').hide().fadeOut(5000);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you add `wmmode="opaque"` to the Flash container?

[Further Reading](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/155/tn_15523.html).

Answer (score 0):

Edit: You could use a callback to load your flash content after the fade effect is complete.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wdm954/S6UKS/2/

Something like this...

```
$('#page').fadeIn(5000, function() {
    //callback
    $('#flash div').show();
});
```

You should wrap the flash though with a fixed size div so the content of the page doesn't need to adjust when the flash shows.

Comment: thanks for your effort, but it does not work, is it posible to see a working demo?

Comment: from your comment, if i was to wrap the flash in a fixed size div, shouldn't the code be $('div #flash').delay(1000).show(); ?

Comment: @gables There was a slight typo in the code. I shouldn't have had the single quotes around the 5000. Try it now, also see demo link.

Answer (score 0):

Flash object is not participating in page's layering scheme. I would add a div, that has position set to absolute, left=0, top=0 z-index=10000, width=page-width (calculated using jquery) and height=page-height(also calculated by jQuery) and then fade out that div. In short overlay the entire page with a white (or other color div) and fade the div out revealing the entire page.

Comment: this did not work for me, it would be great if i could see a demo or working example, thanks